# Why is it that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is not less than $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation

So according to Euler's proof of the Basel problem,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$$

But only for $n  \in  \mathbb{Z}$.

But if $n$ was a positive real and $n \geqslant 1$, then would the sum $S$ be equal to,

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}?$$

If so then after solving the integral via power rule we get $S=1$.

But how can this be since when taking reals, we take integral values as well as new values. So by logic shouldn't, $S>\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ but $1$ isn't. Where am I going wrong pls explain.

Comment: An intergral is not a sum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$S=\int_1^1 \frac{dx}{x^2}=0\quad \neq \quad \sum_{n=1}^1 \frac{1}{n^2}=1$$

To see more in general why inquality doesn't hold you should consider the function $\frac1{x^2}$ and compare with $\frac1{n^2}:=\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor^2}\ge\frac{1}{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}$ to observe that

$$\frac1{x^2} \le \frac{1}{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}\le\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor^2}\implies \int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}\le \int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{\lfloor x\rfloor^2}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

[Plot for latter inequality](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2Fx%5E2,%201%2F(floor(x))%5E2,1%2F(floor(x%5E2))%20from%201%20to%205)

Comment: Thanks the floor func. Helped clarify a bit. The case is closed.

Comment: @Doctorwho2311 I've fixed something that was not completely correct, now it should be ok and even more clear.

Comment: The connection of $x$ ranging over the positive integers and using the floor function to keep $x$ real was ingenious.

Comment: @Doctorwho2311 Yes it is a good way to see it!

Answer (score 7):

In the following picture, the pink area is the left-hand part of the integral $\displaystyle \int_{x=1}^\infty \frac1x \, dx$ while the green and pink areas together are left-hand part of the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$

The green area is the difference, which is clearly positive and is in fact $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} -1\approx 0.6449$
[image]

Comment: Note that you can also use this to show that the sum without the first term is less than the integral and obtain an estimate for the sum.

Comment: @MarkBennet Indeed.  Clearly the difference is between $0.5$ (by the curvature) and $1$ (so the sum converges), and visually is closer to $0.5$

Answer (score 6):

Why should the integral be equal to the sum? To see the sum must be larger,
note that
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^2}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$$
as $x\mapsto 1/x^2$ is a decreasing function.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic doesn't hold because the integrand is a decreasing function so that its *average* value in a unit interval is lower than its *initial* value.

---

As the average value is larger than the *final* value, the following bracketing is guaranteed:

$$\dfrac{\pi^2}6-1<\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}<\dfrac{\pi^2}6.$$

[image]

$\color{lightgreen}{\text{initial}},\color{blue}{\text{average}},\color{magenta}{\text{final}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}-\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\{\frac1{k^2}-\int_k^{k+1}\frac{dx}{x^2}\right\}>0$$
Because in each interval of integration, $$\frac1{k^2}>\frac1{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Each term of the sum is greater than the corresponding part of the integral. Therefore, the sum is greater than the integral.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}-\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2}-\int_k^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2}-\frac1{k(k+1)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k+1)}\\[6pt]
&\ge\frac12\quad\text{(the first term)}
\end{align}
$$

---

The sum is the area of the rectangles $\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)$ and the integral is the area below the curve, $\left(\frac1{k(k+1)}\right)$. The difference is the area of the rectangles above the curve $\left(\frac1{k^2(k+1)}\right)$.

[image]

In the image above, it can be seen that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)=\int_1^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
If $f$ is a decreasing function, then $f(x)\le f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ because $x\ge\lfloor x\rfloor$, and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_1^\infty f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Does not explain in the least to the OP "Where [they are] going wrong pls explain."

Comment: @Did: I've removed the rest of the answer and changed the first step of the "In fact" part to better show how it applies to the difference between the integral and the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly you want to ask why the sum of $1/n^2$ is greater than integral of $1/x^2$ whereas *logically* it should be the other way round. Your argument is that the integral actually tries to sum all the values for $1/x^2$ and not just the ones where $x$ is integer. Sorry!! Thus is wrong. An integral is not summing the values of a function. Rather it is summing product of values of function and the length of subintervals based on which function values are selected. Remember the Riemann sum is not $\sum f(x_i) $ but rather $\sum f(x_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$ and it tends to the value of integral when the subinterval length $x_i-x_{i-1}$ tends to zero.

On the other hand the sum $\sum 1/n^2$ can be easily seen to be some kind of a Riemann sum where interval length is fixed as $1$ so obviously this has to be greater than integral of $1/x^2$ (full justification of this is already available in other answers).

To be precise the idea of an integral is not sum a continuous set of values but rather a limit of a very specific kind of sum. It is however possible to define sum of a continuous set of values (sum over an uncountable index set) but it turns out to be infinite unless each term is $0$.